# How to display this WPF ListView with a vertical toolbar?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, wpk

I'm using PowerShell and the WPK toolkit

the following

```
New-ListView -Name TableView -View {
   New-GridView -AllowsColumnReorder -Columns {
       New-GridViewColumn "title" 
       New-GridViewColumn "dateAdded" 
       New-GridViewColumn "url" 
   }
}
```

is filled with a variable number of rows via

```
    $TableView.ItemsSource = invoke-sqlitequery -sql $ff_sql -connection $conn -asResult 'DataRow'
```

What is missing to get a vertical toolbar ?